# How much renewable energy is curtailed around the world?

Tags: solar-power, renewables, wind-power

CAISO, the California electric grid operator, provides [daily and historical reports](http://www.caiso.com/informed/Pages/ManagingOversupply.aspx) on wind and solar curtailment:

> [image: California wind and solar curtailment by month, 2014 to 2020]

I started looking for similar data from [MISO](https://www.misoenergy.org/), the grid operator where I live, but I wasn't able to find anything.

**What data is available on how much wind and solar generation is curtailed around the world?** I'm looking for historical data by region, but a nation-level or global estimate would also be helpful.

Comment: Some data here: [IEA Renewables 2020](https://www.iea.org/reports/renewables-2020/key-trends-to-watch#are-system-operators-curtailing-too-much-wind-and-solar-electricity).